# Question about integration and sets of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a box, $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded, integrable on $Q$. Suppose $g: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ is another bounded function such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for any $x \in Q \setminus E $ for some closed set $E$ of measure zero, then $g$ is integrable on $Q$ and $\int\limits_Q f = \int\limits_Q g $

### Attempt:

Let $\epsilon >0$. Say $| g(x) | \leq M $ for all $x \in Q$. Since $E$ is closed, then it must be compact. Hence, since $E$ has measure zero, we can select rectangles $\widetilde{Q_i} $ for $i=1,...,k$ such that they cover $E$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k Vol( \widetilde{Q_i} ) < \frac{ \epsilon }{2M}$. Since $f$ is integrable over $Q$, then we can take a partition $P$ of $Q$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $. We refine $P$ by adding the points of the component intervals of the $\widetilde{Q_i}'s$ to the partition $P$, and we can $P'$ this new partition. Hence,

$$ U(g,P') = \sum_R M_R(g) Vol(R) = \sum_R M_R(f) Vol(R) + \sum_{ \widetilde{Q_i} \subseteq R } M_{\widetilde{Q_i}} (g) Vol( \widetilde{Q_i} ) \leq $$

$$ \leq U(f,P') + \frac{\epsilon}{2M} \cdot M \leq U(f,P) + \frac{ \epsilon}{2} $$

Similarly,

$$ L(g,P') = \sum_R m_R(f) Vol(R) + \sum_{ \widetilde{Q_i} \subseteq R } m_{\widetilde{Q_i}} (g) Vol( \widetilde{Q_i} ) \geq \sum_R m_R(f) Vol(R) = L(f,P') \geq L(f,P) $$

Hence,

$$ U(g,P') - L(g,P') \leq U(f,P) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} - L(f,P) < \frac{ \epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon $$

So, $g$ is integrable over $Q$. Now, since $U(g,P') \leq U(f,P) $, then taking inf over all partitions, we obtain $\int_Q g \leq \int_Q f $. Similarly, since $L(g, P') \geq L(f,P)$, then $\int_Q g \geq \int_Q f $ and so

$$ \int\limits_Q f = \int\limits_Q g $$

Is this correct? Any feedback?